# I want to merge all multiple files from each partitions written in spark without using repartitions and coalesce and using maxrecordperfile

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I am using below command in pyspark to write my table with single file per partition thats why I have given 25 mi as max record, whereas only 15 mi is coming in my daily partition, so it should always create 1 file per partition but in my case its creating 20 files approx in each partitions , however earlier it was writting 200 files due to shuffling.

i have already tried repartition and coalesce (1) but it gets hangs due to huge shuffling.

```
final_dedup_df.write.option(“maxRecordsPerFile”, 25000000).format(“parquet”).mode(‘append’).insertInto(“%s.%s”%(db_name,table_name), overwrite=True)
```

output :

```
113.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00009-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
13.6 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00019-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
113.2 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00029-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
113.0 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00047-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.9 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00065-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00083-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00101-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00119-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00137-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.7 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00155-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.6 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00173-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.6 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00191-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
112.6 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00209-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
75.8 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00224-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.5 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00235-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.5 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00245-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.4 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00255-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.3 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00265-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.3 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00275-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.3 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00285-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.3 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00295-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
62.1 M hdfs://labshdpds2/apps/hive/warehouse/dwh_staging.db/dwd_trd_aqc_trade_di/updated_dt=2019-07-01/part-00305-dcab0779-d49a-4dd7-b8fd-76001b02bc04.c000
```

Comment: Suggest you use thd product as it is. Why would you want that?